# Unable to display list items in DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have created the class `DisplayTable`, which was mentioned below.

I have also created one list to add the contents of the class to the list.

I pushed the populated list to the DataGrid. But I'm unable to view those in the DataGrid. Kindly help in fixing this.

```
public class DisplayTable
{
    public int AnalyteId;
    public int UnitCode;
    public int ReferenceValue;
}
```

```
private void btnAddAnalyte_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DisplayTable d = new DisplayTable();
    List<DisplayTable> list = new List<DisplayTable>();
    foreach (CheckBox item in this.AnalyteLitst.Items)
    {
        if (item.IsChecked == true)
        {
            d.AnalyteId = 1;
        }
    }
    foreach (CheckBox unit in this.UnitsList.Items)
    {
        if (unit.IsChecked == true)
        {
            d.UnitCode = 12;
        }
    }
    list.Add(d);
    dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    dataGrid.IsReadOnly = false;
    dataGrid.RowHeight = 30;
    dataGrid.ColumnWidth = 100;
    dataGrid.ItemsSource = list;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DataGrid generates columns automatically only for properties, because each column creates a binding and WPF bindings require *properties*. `DisplayTable` class declares *fields*.

instead of

```
public int AnalyteId;
```

make

```
public int AnalyteId { get; set; }
```

and fix other data members in the same way

Comment: Nice! It also makes sense to set `.AutoGenerateColumns`,`.IsReadOnly`, `.RowHeight`, `.ColumnWidth` once (e.g. in constructor or even better in XAML), not repeat it in each button click

Comment: I need to keep on adding the rows to DataGrid with out disturbing the previous rows, but its always displaying single row. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @NagarajuKuricheti, `List<DisplayTable> list = new List<DisplayTable>();` recreates list on every click so previous items are lost.  insert that line before `private void btnAddAnalyte_Click` and items will be added to existing list. However you need to changed type to ObservableCollection<DisplayTable>  instead of List because List cannot notify UI when items are added

Answer (score -1):

for binding, always use `public properties`.

**change DisplayTable.cs to**

```
public class DisplayTable
{
    public int AnalyteId { get; set; }
    public int UnitCode { get; set; }
    public int ReferenceValue { get; set; }
}
```